# Will pending items be retrieved by REST API?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

There are approve options for some lists. Now we have common users A,B and administrator.

If item1 is created or edited by A, so it is in Appending status. My question is, is this pending item can be retrieved by REST API, by A, B and adminstrator? Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use this sentence

```
...../items?$filter=OData__ModerationStatus eq 2
```

(two underscores between `OData` and `ModerationStatus`)

These are the available statuses:

```
Approved = 0
Rejected = 1
Pending = 2
Draft = 3
```

Comment: Hi,  if B is just a common user, not an approver, will he be able to, or have the access to see the pending items?

Comment: Hi, Robert Lindgren♦, any help?